# Creating sublime ruler macro?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

In Sublime Text 2, is there a way to bind to a key a command that would toggle whether a ruler at 80 characters is shown? I'm aware that it can be set to be permanently on in the settings file but I'd like to be able to turn it on and off at will.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your keymap file:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+r"],  "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "rulers", "value": [80]}},
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+r"],  "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "rulers", "value": []}},
```